# Type or namespace 'RedisClient' could not be found - are you missing a reference?

Tags: servicestack

Ive run into an issue my mono/c# app, when using the nuget version of ServiceStack.Redis on VS2013 on .Net 4.0 I get the compile error

```
Type or namespace 'RedisClient' could not be found - are you missing a reference?
```

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.31.0

```
 using ServiceStack.Redis;


 var client = new RedisClient("localhost");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed the `ServiceStack.Redis` NuGet package?

Comment: I have that installed , I can see IRedisClient along with the other members in intellisense

Comment: `IRedisClient` is only in `ServiceStack.Interfaces`, sounds like `ServiceStack.Redis.dll` is not properly referenced.

Comment: Ugh.. right you are - was calling from unit test project ...rookie error. Thanks